# How to remove the summary grouping of particular row in EXTJS

Tags: extjs, extjs4

If I apply groupField property in the grid and store, extjs will automatically sort records by groupField.

For example: http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/grid/group-summary-grid.html, it used 'project' as groupField.

My Question is How can I add an extra row, which does not belong to any group, into a grid with groupField. (Like this: http://i59.tinypic.com/30s973l.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default group is made for each value from `groupField`, also for empty `groupField` (but it appears first). If it is enough for you then you don't have to do anything.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tme462tj/

When you want to have behavior like on attached image, then some work has to be done.
To put empty value at the end, you can create `convert` function for model field (eg: `convert: function(v) { return v ? v : defaultDepartment; }`). If you want to hide header and summary for this empty group, you can attach event listener to `viewready` event and hide them using styles:

```
viewready: function() {
    var els = this.getEl().query('.x-grid-group-hd');
    els = Ext.Array.filter(els, function(e) { return e.textContent.trim() == defaultDepartment; });

    if (els.length !== 1) {
        return;
    }
    var header = Ext.fly(els[0]);
    header.setStyle('display', 'none');

    var summary = header.up('.x-group-hd-container').down('.x-grid-row-summary');
    if (summary) {
        summary.setStyle('display', 'none');
    }
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hdyokgnx/1/

Comment: thankyou very much, your answer gives me a clearer direction!
But once I collapse others summary group, the default one show up.

Comment: as user3711105 points out, the accepted solution works until the other groups are collapsed. however, the solution works fine if you run this code right after successfully loading the grid.

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment on the accepted solution, this revision makes the grouping header hide permanently for the duration of that grid view.

This solves my problem of needing a grouping grid but with one group that does not have a group header row.

```
store.load
({
    params      :
    {
         arg1   : 1
        ,arg2   : '2'
    }

    ,callback   : function( records, operation, success )
    {
        var els = me.theGrid.getEl().query('.x-grid-group-hd');
        els = Ext.Array.filter( els, function(e)
        {
            return e.textContent.trim().includes( "*** A SUBSTRING IN GROUPING FIELD ***" );
        });


        if (els.length !== 1)
        {
            return;
        }

        var header = Ext.fly(els[0]);
        header.setStyle('display', 'none');

        var summary = header.up('.x-group-hd-container').down('.x-grid-row-summary');
        if (summary)
        {
            summary.setStyle('display', 'none');
        }
    }
});
```